# Amiga mouse trace design

Tags: mouse

I'm only a really rudimentary hobbyist who likes to tinker and was curious about how the various Amiga mice function so I figured I'd ask here since I was stumped about some design choices so here goes:

There a number of different mechanical mice revisions made by a company called Bremen.

I've noticed that some mice have metal caps and a simple set of thin traces for left click, right click,and ground while other mice with tactile switches have big wide traces.  Is there any actual engineering reason for the change in trace width?

[image: Tactile Switches]

[image: Cap Switches]

[image: Tracks]

Comment: less copper to etch when traces are wide ... makes etchant last longer ... also less chance that bad etching causes a break in the trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason from electricity point of view. The traces are already much wider than they need to be for even a few milliamps of current through the buttons.

More likely related to manufacturing.

The less copper needs to be removed, the faster is the process to etch away copper, and you can etch more boards before you need to change the chemical used in the etching process.

Or just different persons designed the different boards and just happened to do what they thought was the simplest thing to do or what they had accustomed to do when designing boads.

So there might not even be any reason and the boards just became to be what they are.